# Как прервать загрузку файла в urllib?

Tags: python

Как прервать загрузку файла в urllib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функцию `urllib.urlretrieve` можно передать параметр `reporthook` - функцию, которая вызывается по окончании загрузки блока данных. Если из неё выкинуть исключение, загрузка прервётся.

- [Документация по urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)
- [Похожий пример на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092272/cancel-slow-download-in-python)